# Adjusting contrast and brightness with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So I am trying to increase both contrast and brightness with OpenCV a bit. This is what I am doing:

```
Mat image_copy;
cvtColor(image, image_copy, CV_BGRA2BGR);
image_copy.convertTo(image, -1, 1.3, 0.15);
```

Image I get though looks very strange. It has blue tint. Red and blue colours are inverted. So my red jumper is blue and a blue can on the table is red.

Why?

I am basically trying to achieve the same effect as when you set contrast to 30 and brightness to 15 here:

http://camanjs.com/examples/

Comment: Do you ever convert back to BGRA? The red-blue swapping is most often caused by treating BGR pixels as RGB, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Richard Knop Did you know how to perform progmatically that vibrance operation which give in the link